# StackLayout's vertical alignment

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to put a button at the bottom of a StackLayout and it's not working.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

[image]

Here's my template:

```
<Page actionBarHidden="true">
    <GridLayout rows="*, *, *, *" columns="*">
        <StackLayout horizontalAlignment="center"
                     verticalAlignment="center">
            <Label text="My Account" id="login-label"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <CardView row="1" class="cardStyle" margin="10"
                  elevation="40"
                  radius="4"
                  verticalAlignment="center"
                  horizontalAlignment="center"
                  rowSpan="2"
                  id="login-box">
            <StackLayout id="form-container">
                <TextField hint="Login"/>
                <TextField hint="Password"/>
                <Label text="Forgot password?" horizontalAlignment="right"/>
                <Button text="Button" @tap="loginButton()" verticalAlignment="bottom"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </CardView>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackLayout do not support that by its design. It is used to just stack the child elements one after another in given orientation, you can't have mixed output - few child elements at top and few at bottom or center.

Use Grid / Dock layout in order to dock an element at bottom.

Comment: but there's an example in the documentation where they are using StackLayout and aligning its children:
https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/layouts/layout-containers#stacklayout
The last example, _ Example for vertical alignment of children_.

Comment: @khalidkaram I think that works in the documentation because they're setting the height of the StackLayout explicitly. I think Manoj is correct, you'd be better off using a grid

Comment: Yes, but they are showcasing about using horizontal alignment in vertical layout and vice versa. Not vertical alignment in vertical layout.